# I am getting "pointer being freed was not allocated"

Tags: c, malloc, free

I am reading from stdin. Since I do not know the length of what I will read, I have to use malloc.

I am getting a **pointer being freed was not allocated**

Sometimes, it happens before free(final), sometimes before free(tmp).

I check that both pointers are correctly are non null after creating them and before making free. Can somebody pin point what I am doing wrong ?

```
total_size = 0;
final = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 1);
if (!final)
{
    printf("Error Allocating Memory for final\n");
    return (NULL);
}
while ((ret = read(0, buf, BUF_SIZE)) > 0)
{
    tmp = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * ft_strlen(final));
    if (!tmp)
    {
        printf("Error Allocating Memory for tmp\n");
        return (NULL);
    }
    strcpy(tmp, final);
    if (final)
        free(final);
    buf[ret] = '\0';
    total_size = total_size + ret;
    final = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * total_size);
    if (!final)
    {
        printf("Error Allocating Memory for final\n");
        return (NULL);
    }
    final = strcat(tmp, buf);
    if (tmp)
        free(tmp);
}
return (final);
```

Comment: What's `ft_strlen`? If the behavior of it is similar to `strlen`, you will get UB right here: `tmp = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * ft_strlen(final));`

Comment: First, don't cast the result of `malloc`.  Why test `final` or `tmp` before `free`?  They must be valued.  Finally, can we see a [mcve]?

Comment: One more thing, decompose this down into smaller parts to expedite debugging.

Comment: Note that at least on the first iteration of your loop, you copy indeterminate data from `*final` into `*tmp`.  It looks like maybe you want to set `*final = '\0'` before entering the loop.

Comment: post the code for `ft_strlen`. Is that function initializing `final` somehow and returning its length? Why is `final` initially allocated with only 1 `char`? Unless `ft_strlen` is working some magic on `final`, that call is most likely UB as is `strcpy(tmp, final);` `final` is never initialized with data, and at best it would point to a single `'\0'` which would return a string length of 0.

Comment: use stderr for error prints and maybe print the errno string. you can use perror() for that.

Comment: ft_strlen is just the same as strlen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem for you:

> ```
> final = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * total_size);
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> ```
> final = strcat(tmp, buf);
> ```

You are leaking the allocated memory and aliasing `*final` and `*tmp`.  You can thereafter free *one* of them, but you must not afterward free the other without first reassigning it to point to a valid dynamically-allocated block.

Overall, it looks like you are going to a lot of unnecessary trouble with `tmp`.  As far as I can tell, you're just trying to increase the size of the block to which `final` points, and that's what `realloc()` is for:

```
size_t desired_size = total_size + ret + 1;  // need space for a terminator
char *tmp = realloc(final, desired_size);
if (!tmp) {
    perror("Error Allocating More Memory for final");
    // realloc() does not free the pointer on failure; at least GLIBC's doesn't
    free(final);
    return (NULL);
}
final = tmp;

buf[ret] = '\0';

// strcat is wasteful if you already know the destination string's length
strcpy(final + total_size, buf);
total_size += ret;
```

The reallocated block may or may not start in the same place as the original, but `realloc()` takes care of copying the data if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are a bit confused when it comes to pointers. 
When you write

```
final = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * total_size);
```

You allocate memory equivalent to `sizeof(char) * total_size`, and malloc then returns the pointer to that memory.
Then you go on to write

```
final = strcat(tmp, buf);
```

Which also returns a a pointer. The memory you allocated with `malloc(...)` is never used. So when you then try to `if (final) free(final);` afterwards, you're not freeing the allocated memory.

Just commenting out

```
if (final)
    free(final);
```

and

```
final = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * total_size);
      if (!final){
          printf("Error Allocating Memory for final\n");
          return (NULL);
      }
```

removed the double free errors. Hope this helps